# Running parallel tests using Selenium Grid and TestNG

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-grid

We have the following set up for running parallel tests using selenium grid and testng.

Selenium Hub : Running the hub.
 Remote Control : Three remote controls running with *firefox as the environment.

We have the `<suite name="Parallel Test Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="34">` for running all the 100 tests in our test suite expecting that each remote control will run 34 test at the same time and three remote controls running 100 at the same time.

But each remote control is executing one test at a time, not concurrently.

IS there any other parameter we should be using to start the hub or the rc.

Help appreciated.

Test Suite contains 100 entries like below

```
<!-- 1 -->
<test name="concurrentJobs100queue01WithFirefoxOnWindows" preserve-order="true">

    <classes>
      <class name="testscripts.concurrentJobs100queue01"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<!-- 2 -->
<test name="concurrentJobs100queue02WithFirefoxOnWindows" preserve-order="true">

    <classes>
      <class name="testscripts.concurrentJobs100queue02"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<!-- 3 -->
<test name="concurrentJobs100queue03WithFirefoxOnWindows" preserve-order="true">

    <classes>
      <class name="testscripts.concurrentJobs100queue03"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<!-- 4 -->
<test name="concurrentJobs100queue04WithFirefoxOnWindows" preserve-order="true">

    <classes>
      <class name="testscripts.concurrentJobs100queue04"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<!-- 5 -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast this came down to resources issue on the test machine. So we ended up getting a cloud service and we could test it for 100s of users. We used BrowserMob which allows you to schedule selenium scripts for N number of users and it uses amazon cloud to run the scripts. Worked really great for us !

Answer (score 0):

It will be like as to run parallely,

```
<test name="concurrentJobs100queue03WithFirefoxOnWindows" preserve-order="true">
<classes>
  <class name="testscripts.concurrentJobs100queue02"/>
  <class name="testscripts.concurrentJobs100queue03"/>
  <class name="testscripts.concurrentJobs100queue04"/>
  <class name="testscripts.concurrentJobs100queue01"/>
</classes>
</test>
```

Comment: This didnt work. It still run one test class at a time. We are trying to run split the 100 test classes among three remote control and run at the same time.

Comment: It works for me, is in class tag name is the class name? as like <class name="com.abc.Selto"/> where Selto is java class name i.e Selto.java only class name will be provided here.